Error in creating external table in amazon redshift
I created a cluster with Amazon redshift. Using this connection, I opened the query editor to create an external table
CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA dynamodb_external_table2
FROM data catalog
database 'dev'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::831926602512:role/redshift-IAM2'
REGION 'us-east-1';

After creating this, I want to create a table inside this external table with data from my S3 bucket and I tried using this
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dynamodb_external_table2.store_table (
    row_id VARCHAR(50),
    product_base_margin VARCHAR(50),
    discount VARCHAR(50),
    ship_date VARCHAR(50),
    quantity_ordered_new VARCHAR(50),
    shipping_cost VARCHAR(50),
    product_sub_category VARCHAR(50),
    sales VARCHAR(50),
    ship_mode VARCHAR(50),
    profit VARCHAR(50),
    order_date VARCHAR(50),
    customer_name VARCHAR(100),
    unit_price VARCHAR(50),
    customer_segment VARCHAR(50),
    state_or_province VARCHAR(50),
    postal_code VARCHAR(20),
    order_id VARCHAR(50),
    product_name VARCHAR(255),
    city VARCHAR(50),
    customer_id VARCHAR(50)
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://store-bucket01/store.csv';

I am getting an error that has to do with the IAM role named redshift-IAM2 even after cross-checking if it attached all the necessary policies
A snapshot of policies attached to IAM role 'redshift-IAM2'
ERROR: Unknown std exception when calling external catalog API: ----------------------------------------------- error: exception name : UnauthorizedException, error type : 136, message: The requested role arn:aws:iam::831926602512:role/redshift-IAM2 is not associated to cluster, should retry : 0 code: 30000 context: query: 0 location: xen_aws_credentials_mgr.cpp:703 process: padbmaster [pid=1073807650] -----------------------------------------------
I expected that my data will correctly imported into the external table since the headings created are the same with the csv file in my S3 bucket. I want to perform further queries after successfully loading this.

I think the error message is fairly clear - "The requested role arn:aws:iam::831926602512:role/redshift-IAM2 is not associated to cluster".
You need to attach roles you want to use inside the Redshift cluster to the cluster at cluster creation or attach it to the cluster using the console or another method of executing the appropriate AWS API call.  The AWS CLI Redshift option is "modify-cluster-iam-roles". Or in the console you can:

Open the Amazon Redshift console
Select Clusters from the navigation menu
Choose the cluster you want to update
Select Manage IAM roles under Actions
Select the IAM roles to add and click Add IAM role
Click Done to save your changes

Once the the role is associated with the cluster you can use it in your SQL.
